# Conflict in the Jackson dependency of amazonaws plugin and redisson plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, jackson, amazon-kinesis, redisson

Currently in my grails project (grails version 2.5.1), I am using amazonaws plugin version 1.11.339 to push the data to kinesis stream. Now I need to save data to redis cache and I am using redisson plugin version 3.10.1 to save the data in redis cache. After using the redisson plugin, I am unable to push the data to kinesis stream due to the jackson dependencies among kinesis and redisson.
I am getting following error logs while pushing data to kinesis stream.

*

> Error | Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Jackson
> jackson-core/jackson-dataformat-cbor incompatible library version
> detected. You have two possible resolutions:      1) Ensure the
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core &
> com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor libraries on
> your classpath have the same version number       2) Disable CBOR
> wire-protocol by passing the -Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.disableCbor property
> or setting the AWS_CBOR_DISABLE environment variable (warning this may
> affect performance) Error |   at
> com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkCborGenerator.getBytes(SdkCborGenerator.java:68)
> Error |   at
> com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.transform.PutRecordRequestMarshaller.marshall(PutRecordRequestMarshaller.java:80)
> Error |   ... 149 more Error | Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.getOutputContext()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/json/JsonWriteContext;
> Error |   at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.close(CBORGenerator.java:903)
> Error |   at
> com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkJsonGenerator.close(SdkJsonGenerator.java:253)
> Error |   at
> com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkJsonGenerator.getBytes(SdkJsonGenerator.java:268)
> Error |   at
> com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkCborGenerator.getBytes(SdkCborGenerator.java:66)
> Error |   ... 150 more

- 

I tried excluding the jackson dependencies from the redisson plugin. But it then did not allow to save the data into redis cache. Could you please suggest the compatible versions for both amazonaws and redisson so that it will solve the issue and work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If jackson dependency from both of the plugins are being conflicted, you can try either of the way.

1. You can either exclude the jackson dependency from one of the plugins (Probably, you can exclude it from the newly added plugins i.e. redisson plugin). Try to clean dependency and re-run the project. May be your dependency hasn't been cleaned and it is causing the issue while saving the data in cache.
2. What scope are you using to add that dependency? If both of them are used as compile. You can try by changing the scope of redisson plugin to runtime.